# What app/skin is this pop up from?

Tags: applications, notifications

This looks like a Samsung theme but i'm not sure and like the look of it. What app or theme is this pop up notification from?

[image]

Comment: Looks like a custom theme with a custom ROM...

Comment: Using the Google Image Search I found it's the "Material Design Flat Theme".